# Kali not showing GUI when raspberry starts

Tags: pi-2, gui, kali

When I turn on my Raspberry Pi 2 with Kali Linux, the screen is still off and does not receive any signal. But if I connect with SSH, log as root/toor, startxfce4 and reboot the screen turns on with the GUI showing the Desktop.

I tried this on a Raspberry Pi 3, another SD Card and other screens but it's still doing the same thing. I need to connect first through SSH to send the signal.

I tried to use raspi-config and to modify the config.txt file but everything is still the same.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What's the output of `systemctl get-default`?

Comment: @Aurora0001  Output: graphical.target